# How can I extract only the name field from json by using gcloud command?

Tags: json, bash, shell, awk, terminal

I am new to gcp and linux. I am trying to get the name from the `json` format using the `gcloud` command.
Below is the command and output:

```
gcloud firestore indexes composite list --format=json
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "fieldPath": "is_active",
        "order": "ASCENDING"
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "created_at",
        "order": "DESCENDING"
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "__name__",
        "order": "ASCENDING"
      }
    ],
    "name": "projects/emc-ema-simcs-d-286404/databases/(default)/collectionGroups/customer/indexes/CICAgNjbhowK",
    "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
    "state": "READY"
  }
```

How can I get the `name` value using gcloud command.
I tried using: `gcloud firestore indexes composite list | grep name | awk -F'name: ' '{print $2}'` but this didn't give any output.

Please help!

Thanks
Pritish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to get the `name` value using the below command:

`gcloud firestore indexes composite list --format=json | grep '"name"' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'`

Output:

```
projects/emc-ema-simcs-d-xxxxxx/databases/(default)/collectionGroups/customer/indexes/CICAgNjbhowK
```

Comment: You never need `grep` when you're using `awk`, nor do you need to pipe `awk` output to another `awk`, and `-F' '` sets `FS` to the default value it already has. `grep '"name"' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'` = `awk '/"name"/{split($2,f,/"/); print f[2]}'` which can be abbreviated to `awk -F'"' '/"name"/{print $4}'` but you should be using `jq` to parse JSON anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Google CLI's format flag can also query the json that the command returns.
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats

`gcloud firestore indexes composite list --format="json(name)"`

I believe this command will return an array of objects with only the name property.

Comment: To get just the value `--format="get(name)` - [gcloud topic formats](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats)

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your tool output doesn't **really** have an unmatched `[` at the start that'd make it invalid JSON as in the example you provided in your question and instead either has both `[` and `]` or has neither, i.e. it is valid JSON.

If the output starts with `[` and ends with `]` then you'd use `jq` as:

```
gcloud firestore indexes composite list --format=json | jq -r '.[0] .name'
```

Otherwise you'd use `jq` as:

```
gcloud firestore indexes composite list --format=json | jq -r '.name'
```

For example, using `cat file<N>` in place of `gcloud firestore indexes composite list --format=json` which I don't have:

```
$ cat file1
[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "fieldPath": "is_active",
        "order": "ASCENDING"
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "created_at",
        "order": "DESCENDING"
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "__name__",
        "order": "ASCENDING"
      }
    ],
    "name": "projects/emc-ema-simcs-d-286404/databases/(default)/collectionGroups/customer/indexes/CICAgNjbhowK",
    "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
    "state": "READY"
  }
]
$
$ cat file1 | jq -r '.[0] .name'
projects/emc-ema-simcs-d-286404/databases/(default)/collectionGroups/customer/indexes/CICAgNjbhowK
```

```
$ cat file2
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "fieldPath": "is_active",
        "order": "ASCENDING"
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "created_at",
        "order": "DESCENDING"
      },
      {
        "fieldPath": "__name__",
        "order": "ASCENDING"
      }
    ],
    "name": "projects/emc-ema-simcs-d-286404/databases/(default)/collectionGroups/customer/indexes/CICAgNjbhowK",
    "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
    "state": "READY"
  }
$
$ cat file2 | jq -r '.name'
projects/emc-ema-simcs-d-286404/databases/(default)/collectionGroups/customer/indexes/CICAgNjbhowK
```

Comment: Thanks Ed. I wanted to get the list of names from json, so used your command. `gcloud firestore indexes composite list --format=json | jq -r '.name'`

Thanks for the help